# AvFoundation takes black image from camera in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

I am newbie to iPhone and have made a demo using `AVFoundation` for taking pics. I am taking 5 max images but issue is when I am taking 1st image it always come as compare to other images. Can anybody help me to resolve it? Code is as below:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

//Added by jigar
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;
//[[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] supportsAvCaptureSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];

//End
// Create device input and add to current session
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
[session addInput:input];

// Create video output and add to current session
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[session addOutput:output];

// Start session configuration
[session beginConfiguration];
[device lockForConfiguration:nil];

// Set torch to on
if(flashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeAuto)
{
    device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeAuto;
}
else if(flashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn){
    device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOn;
}
else if(flashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff){
    device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOff;
}

[device unlockForConfiguration];
[session commitConfiguration];
//    [session startRunning];
[currentPicker takePicture];
//        [session stopRunning];
//        session = nil;
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and try to be more clear about what exactly is not working, what you tried, expected and results? Also, are you sure, the user has allowed camera access, as you are not checking that?

Comment: Any update on this?